# how to communicate values between fragments in android?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

1. I have an android activity with 4 fragments.
2. In Each fragment, there exists a text box, On the 4th fragment, a button exists.
3. on clicking the button, all the values(numbers) present in the text-boxes in the different fragment is added together and displayed as a `Toast`.
4. Note: Fragments must not communicate with each other.(without use of static variables or public in fragments and access it in the 4th fragment.)

Now, I have fragments but i need to know What communication technique should i have to use in this case?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html. Check the docs

Comment: Use a callback method... create a interface implement it in the 3 fragments get the value in the 3 fragments... create a 2nd interface onclick implement by your parentactivity and call it in your 4th fragment using callback

Comment: @bean_droid Could you explain with code for get value and onclick interfaces?

Comment: @Duke have you figured it out?

Comment: @A.S your solution worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could store the Data in the MainActivity and read it from any Fragment like:

```
//MainActivity
private String mItem = "";

public void getItem(){
    return this.mItem;
}

public void addItem(String searchItem){
    this.mItem += searchItem;
}


//FRAGMENT 1
public void onButtonClick(){        
    //adding a string to your item in the MainActivity
    ((MainActivity)getActivity()).addItem("String from Frag1");

}



//FRAGMENT 4
private void onButtonClick{
    //reading the string
    String toastMessage =  ((MainActivity)getActivity()).getItem();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way i think  you could do this is by communicating through the activity by using getActivity() from each fragment since they all share the same activity

Answer (score 0):

Before calling another fragment just put code below:

```
Bundle bundle=new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("MY_DATA", mStringData);
            mFragment.setArguments(bundle);
```

After commit() mFragment. In second fragment where you want to get this data use:

```
String data = getArguments().getStringExtra("MY_DATA");
```

Another way for this in your case, you can use SharedPreference
Save data in preference like:

```
SharedPreference mPreference=PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(MainActivity.this);
```

mPreferences.edit().putString("MY_DATA", mStringData).commit();

to get this data in another fragment use:

```
String data = mPrefrences().getStringExtra("MY_DATA");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public interface IAddItem{ public void addItem(int fragID, String value) };
```

Create this interface and implement it to your MainActivity:

```
    Public class MainActivity extends Activity implements IAddItem{
      private String mValue; 
      public void addItem(int fragID, String value){
         switch(fragID){
           case R.id.frag_1:
            mValue = value;
            break;
           case //Do your other code here
        }
      }

   }
```

In using it in other fragments using this: `private IAddItem mCallback;`

```
 @Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);

    // This makes sure that the container activity has implemented
    // the callback interface. If not, it throws an exception
    try {
        mCallback = (IAddItem) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement IAddItem");
    }
}
```

And call it like this: `mCallback.addItem(R.id.frag_1, text.getText().toString());`